# Website works fine in Opera, but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, opera

[This website](http://ac-diseno.com.ar/en.html) works fine in Opera. But when trying to navigate it with Chrome I find that the "*About Me*" and "*Contact*" sections, as well as the *footer*, don't allow me to click on links or fill the forms properly.

Any ideas why it works in one browser but not in the other? I haven't changed anything about the html, but one day the site just stopped working like it's supposed to with Chrome.

Comment: works for me but does mess up with graphics, blame Google.

Comment: Can you even fill the "Message..." form in Chrome? I click on it and it does nothing. I can't even type.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: swfobject is not defined en.html:432`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas well i got dev version...

Answer (score 0):

Your end FORM tag is nested and not on the same level in the DOM.

```
<div id="divboton">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="buttonsubmit" />
     </form>
</div>
```

Should be

```
<div id="divboton">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="buttonsubmit" />
</div>
</form>
```

Chrome mustn't like it. I used tag inspector to comment out the form and the footer links worked.

Comment: I corrected that, thanks!
But the site keeps being broken:
*I can't click on the "Estudios Media" link
*I can't fill out the form
*The Facebook, Twitter, etc. links don't work.

Comment: You've got loads of html errors. There's an extra end script tag in the head. Check this: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fac-diseno.com.ar%2Fen.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I get a lot of "itemprop" and "itemtype" errors, but those codes are copied from microdata directives. Why is the validator counting them as errors?

Comment: I have corrected many errors, @Papa. I'm trying to get around the microdata ones now. I still don't understand why Opera works fine and Chrome refuses to render the page properly.

Comment: I'd recommend disregarding alot of the itemprop stuff. Just look for vital html errors. Given you're using a lot of different javascript plugins, I would remove them for now. You're also embedding the 4 javascript files 6 times. Remove all the javascript and get the css working.